# Find the generator of the following two cyclic groups, $(\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z, +)$ and $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z, +)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Since both of these groups are under addition would the generator of these two groups be one?  For example $[2]$ in $(\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z, +)$  would just be $[1]$+$[1]$=$[2]$?  Is this logic correct or am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: Yes, your approach is correct! Infact, you can prove using some elementary number theory that $\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$ is just the set of remainders (eqiuvalence classes) that we get after dividing by $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each group is generated by $1$, yes.  But there are more generators.  Every $k$ between $0$ and $n$ and relatively prime to $n$ will be a generator of $\Bbb Z_n$.   (The number of these is $\varphi (n)$, where $\varphi $ is Euler's totient function. )

So, in the case of $\Bbb Z_6$, both $1$ and $5$ are generators.